# What happens when we issue a destroy method in jQuery UI

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, widget, destroy

What goes on behind the scenes when we `destroy` a jQuery ui widget.

ex: `$('#test').tabs('destroy')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you take a look at the source code of the widget factory you'll notice that what happens is that it will remove excess elements, classes and bound events that was added to the DOM by the widget when it first initialized. In short, it will effectively restore the target element to its original state.

This is a excerpt from [line 188 of the widget factory](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/master/ui/jquery.ui.widget.js#L188):

```
destroy: function() {
    this._destroy();
    // we can probably remove the unbind calls in 2.0
    // all event bindings should go through this._bind()
    this.element
        .unbind( "." + this.widgetName )
        .removeData( this.widgetName );
    this.widget()
        .unbind( "." + this.widgetName )
        .removeAttr( "aria-disabled" )
        .removeClass(
            this.widgetBaseClass + "-disabled " +
            "ui-state-disabled" );

    // clean up events and states
    this.bindings.unbind( "." + this.widgetName );
    this.hoverable.removeClass( "ui-state-hover" );
    this.focusable.removeClass( "ui-state-focus" );
},
```

Widgets implement their own clean-up routines by prototyping the *internal* method `_destroy` (which is a no-op method in the factory, i.e. it doesn't do anything; you can see that it is called at the start of the `destroy` method). Excerpt from [line 466 of the Tabs widget](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/master/ui/jquery.ui.tabs.js#L466) looks like this:

```
_destroy: function() {
    var o = this.options;

    if ( this.xhr ) {
        this.xhr.abort();
    }

    this.element.removeClass( "ui-tabs ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all ui-tabs-collapsible" );

    this.list.removeClass( "ui-tabs-nav ui-helper-reset ui-helper-clearfix ui-widget-header ui-corner-all" );

    this.anchors.each(function() {
        var $this = $( this ).unbind( ".tabs" );
        $.each( [ "href", "load" ], function( i, prefix ) {
            $this.removeData( prefix + ".tabs" );
        });
    });

    this.lis.unbind( ".tabs" ).add( this.panels ).each(function() {
        if ( $.data( this, "destroy.tabs" ) ) {
            $( this ).remove();
        } else {
            $( this ).removeClass([
                "ui-state-default",
                "ui-corner-top",
                "ui-tabs-active",
                "ui-state-active",
                "ui-state-disabled",
                "ui-tabs-panel",
                "ui-widget-content",
                "ui-corner-bottom"
            ].join( " " ) );
        }
    });

    return this;
},
```